# MSCRM 4 How to use an "Already Set Lookup value" to trigger actions for OnLoad/OnChange

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

Today I was asked to see if we can preset our Payment terms
When "Company X" is selected in our Partner To Invoice field
I tried several ways using the "Var xml" lookup and changing it from systemuser to the accountid.
Does anyone have anyway of doing this?

```
if(crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue == "Company X"){
//insert code here to do something here
}
```

Only due to it being a lookup field, there isn't an easy way that I know of to do a comparison.

I know what *Value* I want to compare the value to but not sure how to pull it out to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out I just referenced

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189833.aspx

and made my own version of the code using "var"

```
if(crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue != null){

var partnername = crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue[0].id;
// alert(partnername);  // used to find out the LookUp ID number
// Exampled Result: "{AEB4E2EF-C2E9-DE11-B076-000E0F0000E0}"

if(partnername == "{AEB4E2EF-C2E9-DE11-B076-000E0F0000E0}"){
crmForm.all.new_paymentterms.DataValue = 60; 
crmForm.all.new_paymentterms.Disabled = true; // used 
// alert("This Account has a default payment terms of 60 days.")
}
}
else{crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue == null
crmForm.all.new_paymentterms.Disabled = false;
}
```

or if you would like to use the comparison by the actual text of the lookup field

```
if(crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue != null){

var partnername = crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue[0].name;
// alert(partnername);  // used to find out the LookUp ID number
// Exampled Result: "Company X"

if(partnername == "Company X"){
crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue = 60; 
crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.Disabled = true; // used 
// alert("This Account " +  partnername 
+ '\n' + '\n' +  " has a default payment terms of 60 days.")
}
}
else{crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue == null
crmForm.all.new_paymentterms.Disabled = false;
}
```

Cleaned: Code below

```
try{
    if(crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue != null){
    var partnername = crmForm.all.<lookupfield>.DataValue[0].name;
    if(partnername == "Company X"){
            // Insert your code here
            }
            }
            else{
            //Optional Code here if you want the nothing then insert nothing here
            }
        }
catch(err){alert("Error in pulling the Lookup Field Name")}
```